I can access by IP but NOT by fqdn to apache2 virtual host from another device on the same network or virtual guest on the same machine
I have apache2 running on my debian host with 3 virtualhosts. I can access these virtual hosts' pages by their servernames on the host but I cant access the pages on another device on the same network or virtual guest hosted by same machine where virtualhosts served by using the servernames. I can only access by IP.
All my "hosts" files is set up correctly so I can ping using fqdn. All ports are open and apache2 listens all incoming IPs.
What can be wrong with my setup?

What happens when you try to access the server by fqdn? Do you see the client connecting to the correct or wrong IP? Does the server see the incoming connection?

I see on browser ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I try to access the server by fqdn. When I ping the fqdn it connects to correct server ip. I see no new entries on apache2 access log after trying to connect to server. Is there any other way I can check connections live on apache2? I could not be able to understand the problem.

I checked with chrome internal dns resolver that it resolves to 127.0.0.1 instead of the server ip even hosts file includes webserver.localhost entry correctly on windows @u1686_grawity . How can I achive browser to correctly get subdomains of localhost ips correctly?

FQDN applies to WAN, for LAN it's local domain only. On Windows, three things are required (1 & 3 for Linux): (1) Devices must have static IPs set on the router, (2) Workgroup name must match the local domain set on the router (Linux allows specifying, which still must be done, whereas on Windows, Workgroup name is the local domain name), (3) hosts must have entries for all devices to be accessed via local domain names. Without 1, the router has no idea how to route the local domain traffic and the router sets the local domain name used that must be echoed across all devices

I found the solution @JW0914 . My domain was a subdomain of localhost like website1.localhost where localhost ip is hard coded to 127.0.0.1 ip address on the OS. So the ip cant be changed for localhost subdomains. Assigning website1.somedomain to the ip of the server solved the problem.

I found the problem that subdomains of localhost can not be reached from external machine. in my case mysite.localhost on host machine can not be reached by browser from another machine adding "ip mysite.localhost" that doesnt work. The solution is to change domain of localhost to something else which works! the main thing is to obey the rule of strictly defined localhost domain to 127.0.0.1 ip address. Localhost can not be redirected to some other ip address especially on browser.
